# R: Is there a way to round to 1 decimal place in table1 for continuous variables?

Tags: r

Is there a way to round to 1 decimal place for continuous variables in the table1 package? Looking at the documentation, there seems to be a way to do number of significant figures but there does not seem to be a way to round to 1 decimal place.
Here is some example code:

```
table1(~cyl +disp + hp, data = mtcars)
```

and here is the output (does 3 significant figures automatically but I can't figure out how to round to a current number of decimal points).

[image]

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You can like a look at this [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html), it did include some tricks to round numbers using `table1`.

Comment: [tag:table1] != [tag:datatable]. The tag-recommendation (on Stack and elsewhere) is imperfect, please check the tags it recommends, read what they are about (mouse-over or similar), and make sure you do not include unrelated tags. I fixed it here.

Answer (score 2):

```
my.render.cont <- function(x) {
    with(stats.default(x), 
         c("",
           
          "Mean (SD)" = sprintf("%s (%s)",
                                round_pad(MEAN, 1),
                                round_pad(SD, 1)),
         
          "Median (Min, Max)" = sprintf("%s (%s, %s)",
                                       round_pad(MEDIAN, 1), 
                                       round_pad(MIN, 1), 
                                       round_pad(MAX, 1)))
    )
}


table1(~cyl +disp + hp, data = mtcars,
       render.continuous=my.render.cont)
```

[image]